# How I can rise above this div?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this sample

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ck3pux8x/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="banner">

</div>


<div class="inner">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.left,.main,.right{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}

.left{
    background:red;
}
.main{
    background:blue;
}
.right{
    background:aqua;
}

.banner{width:300px;background:yellow;height:100px;}
```

I want to move div on the right (.right) to be in line with div website (banner) without changing HTML code (just CSS).

I tried to add `margin-top:-6em` look different on other resolutions.

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `margin-top: -100px;`, since that is the actual height if the banner pushing everything else down. That should work with different solutions. However keep in mind that this is ugly. It is against the idea of the html markup flow.

Comment: And what solution would you recommend besides that?

Comment: Obviously changing the html markup. The markup defines the flow of the content. If you want that `div.right` anchored to the banner, then it simply should not be contained in the `div.inner`, since the flow places its content _below_ the banner for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only change the CSS, you have to use `margin-top:-100px` instead of `margin-top:-6em` if you want to align it. https://jsfiddle.net/ck3pux8x/1/

But the best solution would be changing the HTML to move the .right div outside the .inner an place it next to the .banner and make .banner float right. https://jsfiddle.net/ck3pux8x/2/

Answer (score 0):

HI now try to this define your `body` `position` `relative` and your class `.right` `position` `absolute` and `left` or `top` **according** to your **requirement** .

**as like  this**

```
body{
position:relative;
}
.right {
    background: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Demo

```css
.right{
  position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  top:0;
 }
body{position : relative;}
.left,.main,.right{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}

.left{
    background:red;
}
.main{
    background:blue;
}
.right{
    background:aqua;
}

.banner{width:300px;background:yellow;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    
</div>


<div class="inner">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relative` re-`position`ing in this case:

```
.right{
    background:aqua;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ck3pux8x/4/